# ASP: 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Полный текст ошибки:
**403 - Forbidden: Access is denied
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials**

В общем имеется проект WebForms.
В папке Content лежат страницы, защищенные от неавторизованных пользователей.
В корне лежит Login.aspx страница. Все запросы к страницам в папке Content, при условии что пользователь не авторизирован, перенаправляются на Login.aspx.
При удачной авторизации, со страницы Login.aspx перенаправляются на defaultUrl.

```
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);
```

**Web.config:**

```
    <location path="content">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow users = "*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Content/Default.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
</system.web>
```

На локальном сервере все отлично, но на удаленном выдает ошибку 403..

Причем не при всех запросах, если конкретно прописать в адресной строке:
**http://website.com/application_path/Content/Default.aspx**
то страница отобразится, а если: **http://website.com/application_path/** то нет..

Похоже что что то не так со стартовой страницей, у меня стоит: /Content/Default.aspx

Comment: при любом запросе? либо к какой-то конкретной папке? В любом случае, стоит проверить имеет ли IIS доступ к этим папкам, вполне возможно, что нет

Comment: тогда стоит проверить разрешения доступа этой папки для пользователя под которым IIS работает

Comment: [похожий вопрос на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8)